# Struts search application within website of without database

Tags: java, struts

i'm new to java struts.
actly i want to create an application in which i want to search within the website static pages,which has no database. i.e. if user enter the search string then the corresponding results are shown to user.

Comment: Addon Google custom site search for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start with a Struts tutorial (http://j2ee.masslight.com/Chapter4.html for example) to get the bones of your application up and running, namely your textbox and button.

Struts is an MVC framework with a 'M'. By that I mean the implemention of your model is completely up to you. So when it comes time to write your Action class you can do anything you want. From the sounds of it you want parse an HTML file so you can either load it using java.io if it's stored on the server or load it from where ever.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of a 'database'. There are some good search engines out there (like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)) that can index your html and store this in an index file on your file system. The semantics come in on whether you believe this index is a 'database' or not.

Most of the search engines come with an HTML crawler and parser out-of-the-box so your requirement to have something search through your content (especially when it is not publicly available to be indexed by the likes of Google), should not be insurmountable.